# Cgo cannot file standard c++ headers

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to compile a go file that uses cgo to include C++ class.
The C++ class is included via a C wrapper.
When I run `go run main.go` I get the following error:

```
...
In file included from some_file.h:
./general_types.h:4:10: fatal error: 'cinttypes' file not found
#include <cinttypes>
```

The file structure is as follows

-- cmd/main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "testpackage/testlib"
)

func main() {
    p := testlib.New(0)
    ...
}
```

-- /testlib/testlib.go

```golang
package testlib

// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
// #include "testlib_c.hpp"
import "C"
import "unsafe"


type TestClass struct {
    testclass_t *C.testclass_t
}

func New(code int) *TestClass {
    pt := new(TestClass)
    pt.testclass_t = C.testclass_init(C.itype(code))
    return pt
}
...
```

--- /testlib/testlib_c.hpp - C-wrapper for the C++ class in testlib.hpp

```c
#pragma once
#include "testlib.hpp"


typedef struct testclass_t  {
    testclass *obj;
} testclass_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

testclass_t* testclass_init(itype c);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And testlib.hpp includes another header file that includes standard C++ headers which cannot be found:

```c
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cmath> 
#include <regex>
```

Comment: 1. Stop doing go run main.go. Now and forever. 2. Run go build with -x to see actual invocations. 3. Fiddle with CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS until your C compiler finds your headers.